# Wrongly closed question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

Recently I asked a question which IMHO was wrongly closed (because it was quite specific).

You can even see a reply from (high rep) user **tao** who says he was planning to write an answer.
Please check here

[Disadvantage of storing date in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956766/disadvantage-of-storing-date-in-utc)

I really would like to get feedback from community here to judge if it was correctly closed.
If not tell me why was it off topic?

Comment: FYI, your note at the top of your question will be displayed as a short description of your question in question lists. I doubt it'll attract the attention you want.

Comment: The description of the Needs more Focus close reason says: *"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."*. Having a bullet list of questions falls right into that category...

Comment: There are several comments already that tell you why it's off-topic. In short - there is no concrete problem. We cannot enumerate every possible issue you might have because...technically, you should have exactly zero issues. If you *do*, then there exactly a bajillion things that either you or somebody else (or both) have done wrong. I don't think we can give you a bajillion good answers to cover all of these.

Comment: @VLAZ So a question which asks to list disadvantages of an approach has bajillion answers?

Comment: @dan-beginner yes. Precisely a bajillion. As I said - there are no actual issues. Any problem you do have is from something *else* going wrong. There is a bajillion of those.

Comment: Up to three bajillions.

Comment: @dan-beginner generally speaking, SO isn't appropriate for curating speculative lists of things, i.e. "I'm planning on doing X, please provide a list of all the things that could go wrong". Prefer concrete, specific, answerable problems with narrow scope.

Comment: @ggorlen That is why I don't understand why is asking to list disadvantages of an approach speculative?

Comment: @VLAZ So what about comment from tao? Didn't he spot a problem?

Comment: @dan-beginner do you have a *concrete problem*? No. Then we have to speculate what problems you *might* have.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah so when I say what is downside of using an exponential time algorithm? Instead of answering it **can be unusable with large data**, you call  that a speculation?

Comment: The fact that a user (regardless of reputation) might want to answer a questions does **not** make it automatically acceptable.

Comment: @dan-beginner the comment from tao is a speculative problem that will happen if you're not using UTC as you should. That's not what you're doing. Because there is no code in your question that shows any misuse (or any use). I can also say that it'd be wrong to multiply the minute value by two. But that's not really a problem with using UTC.

Comment: @VLAZ What about DST? Like here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing ?

Comment: Again, Ok, just it sadly feels the community here is prioritizing to close, over helping, that's it.

Comment: No mention of what you do with it when sent to server. Nobody answering can guess that if you don't specify it

Comment: @charlietfl I wrote it " Then I was assuming the server would send me back time also in UTC time zone"

Comment: @dan-beginner DST is handled by conversion. Look, do you or do you not have a concrete problem that you have a question about? And no "are there any disadvantages you might imagine" is **not** a concrete problem. If you have a *concrete* and *answerable* problem, feel free to edit your question to focus on it. Until then, I don't feel like trying to speculate more on what might go wrong in imaginary situations that might or might not apply to your code.

Comment: Again, it just feels that way, but the people answering you are really, in fact and for sure trying to help you.  They are explaining why the question you are asking is too hard to answer, pointing you to different forums for that question, and still listing *speculative* issues that might occur as examples of why the question isn't answerable.  Not only are they trying to help you, they are doing it out of good will to a beginner, and not for any reward, especially since the question is now closed and there is no possibility of reputation change.  They're just being nice to a beginner.

Comment: But that is vague without knowing exactly how is it stored, any processing done to it etc

Comment: @dan-beginner It certainly is easier to blame the community than yourself, I agree. The fact that you're unwilling to introspect and examine your own stance is honestly what is sad to me. I know Stack Overflow has its issues, but the fact that the comments were full of people trying to help you bring the question into focus says, to me, that our system was working as designed.

Comment: @dan-beginner "what is downside of using an exponential time algorithm?" is also very much off-topic. Sometimes exponential algorithms are optimal or `n` is guaranteed small enough that it doesn't matter -- throwing out complex scenarios without any context and asking what could go wrong isn't specific, concrete or answerable. It's not helpful to future visitors because it's so speculative. Your question is like: "I'm thinking of a number. Can you guess it?" We prioritize helping, but the nature of your question isn't possible to help with because it's out of scope.

Comment: @ggorlen What is disadvantage of manual memory management in C++ ? Also off topic?  Also too broad?

Comment: @dan-beginner Yes, that's too broad. Please read [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center. Almost any question of the form "list the disadvantages of <broad concept in computing>" is off-topic. [Gorilla vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) might also help.

Comment: @ggorlen Just curious where in help center says disadvantage of smth is off topic?

Comment: @dan-beginner - "What is disadvantage of manual memory management in C++?" - Your question wasn't about C++ it was about JavaScript and some unspecified problem with UTC Date Time.

Comment: @dan-beginner Ironically, the help center is unable to contain an exhaustive list of each and every off-topic scenarios because there are an infinite number. The help center says on topic are "specific programming problems" (your question doesn't offer one) and off-topic includes "too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based". I expect new community members to familiarize themselves with the scope of questions on the site before participating. When your post is closed, instead of being defensive, why not listen and work with the commenters to improve your question?

Comment: "*Just curious where in help center says disadvantage of smth is off topic?*" it's under the umbrella of [these](https://i.imgur.com/fCbt0PS.png) and it's [not these](https://i.imgur.com/PXcxv3L.png)

Comment: Well, that's a mess if I ever saw one (not messier than dealing with dates, though). @dan-beginner, FYI, arguments by analogy are not usually well-met here as they are highly susceptible to fallacy. More on point, the question seems to be too abstract for its own good (it would fare much better if you actually *sent* a UTC date to the server, expected the same thing *back* and then got *something else* in return).

Comment: Just for some more context on how broad the topic is - even single case @dan-beginner you are looking for took 10+ pages to explain - https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/. The linked question is asking for a full list of of such cases (and for SO answer each would require good explanation with solution) - so there is really no way to fit *complete and verifiable correct*  answer into SO.

Comment: *"Again, Ok, just it sadly feels the community here is prioritizing to close, over helping, that's it."* -- Kind of. This isn't a "help site" per se, and many new users of the site can become frustrated by not understanding this. It's a question and answer site where both questions and answer quality are moderated by site users and for questions to remain open and be answered, they need to meet site standards, standards that you may not agree with, but if you wish to ask questions on the site, that you'll want to learn.

Comment: And now dan-beginner's account is deleted apparently. Kind of curious since this meta post does not follow the usual outrage pattern that precedes such a decision. Oh well, you can't convince them all I guess.

Comment: @Gimby - btw, by the time I got here, the *chat* already displayed them as a deleted account, so it seems like they scheduled for deletion before or during their take to meta. It was probably better to dupe close than waging the broad/well-scoped war (5-sec search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66925598/11407695)

Answer (score 25):

You are entirely unaware how broad and messy the topic of times and time zones really is. You may think you’re asking a relatively focused question, but you’re not. One could write entire books about time handling and its pitfalls, and that’s the very definition of a too broad question. Even if your question wasn’t about time in particular, “list things that could go wrong” in itself is an open ended question by nature, thus doubly off topic. You have been given many nudges how you could focus your question more; do that.

Comment: " You have been given many nudges how you could focus your question more" --> Well more or less. Yes but I also have to raise concerns when I feel I am wrongly treated. That is good for Stack Overflow too. I didn't think and don't think still that questions of type to **list disadvantages of something are broad**.

Comment: Dunning-Kruger.  When I first started doing this I had no formal training or education, and as a hobby coder what I found when I made the transition into professional coder was that I didn't even know the right questions or even terms to google.  It took about a year to get that, during which time I was often trapped into accepting jobs that were much harder than I had imagined, so I didn't charge nearly what an experienced coder would have, because they would have realized that the situation was much more complex than I did.

Comment: @deceze e.g. I will try to focus on what I don't understand in this answer specifically for example next time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing. Would that be better?

Comment: @dan Again, you might have thought your question was relatively simple going into it, but you’ve been told repeatedly that it isn’t. Believe it.

Comment: Dunning-Kruger absolutely applies, because you seem to be overestimating your understanding of the problem, even with multiple people trying to point out the gaps in your knowledge, and thus inability to formulate a question.

Notice in the answer you are referring to that the answerer gives *concrete* examples of issues that might arise, and the answers to what the application should do in those cases are unknown to him, so the answer basically consists of questions about specific circumstances which would have to be defined by the person asking the question.

Comment: @deceze I take that. So I plan to ask specifically what I didn't understand in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing. better idea?

Comment: @dan Yes. Quote specific parts you have questions about and ask focused questions about them.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland The problem occured because I couldn't imagine if asking for specific disadvantages of an approach was off topic. In the answer I referred to I didn't understand what situations that person was talking about (3rd and 4th paragraph). I will look into the above comment from deceze as recommendation.

Comment: Short answer: it's off topic *here*. My experience is in practical coding for specific situations, and Stack Overflow is for practical answers to specific problems encountered when tackling specific situations. You want a more general answer from a software engineer's perspective, which is why I linked you to the software engineering stack exchange.  Specific to that 3rd paragraph: do you understand the issue that's being referenced? Sometimes your application can encounter events that are out of order in *local time* but not in UTC.  Also, extended discussion should be done in chat.